# Most efficient way to add new keys or append to old keys in a dictionary during iteration in Python?

Tags: python, iteration

Here's a common situation when compiling data in dictionaries from different sources:

Say you have a dictionary that stores lists of things, such as things I like:

```
likes = {
    'colors': ['blue','red','purple'],
    'foods': ['apples', 'oranges']
}
```

and a second dictionary with some related values in it:

```
favorites = {
    'colors':'yellow',
    'desserts':'ice cream'
}
```

You then want to iterate over the "favorites" object and either append the items in that object to the list with the appropriate key in the "likes" dictionary or add a new key to it with the value being a list containing the value in "favorites".

There are several ways to do this:

```
for key in favorites:
    if key in likes:
        likes[key].append(favorites[key])
    else:
        likes[key] = list(favorites[key])
```

or

```
for key in favorites:
    try:
        likes[key].append(favorites[key])
    except KeyError:
        likes[key] = list(favorites[key])
```

And many more as well...

I generally use the first syntax because it feels more pythonic, but if there are other, better ways, I'd love to know what they are. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), where the default value is a new `list` instance.

```
>>> import collections
>>> mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

In this way calling `.append(...)` will always succeed, because in case of a non-existing key `append` will be called on a fresh empty list.

You can instantiate the `defaultdict` with a previously generated list, in case you get the dict `likes` from another source, like so:

```
>>> mydict = collections.defaultdict(list, likes)
```

Note that using `list` as the `default_factory` attribute of a `defaultdict` is also discussed as an example in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples).

Comment: 2.5 and onwards only, or you have to define your own defaultdict class.

Answer (score 3):

Use collections.defaultdict:

```
import collections

likes = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, value in favorites.items():
    likes[key].append(value)
```

`defaultdict` takes a single argument, a factory for creating values for unknown keys on demand.  `list` is a such a function, it creates empty lists.

And iterating over .items() will save you from using the key to get the value.

Comment: Good tip on using .items(). That's one of the things I love about Python. There's always a better, faster, smarter way.

Answer (score 2):

Except defaultdict, the regular dict offers one possibility (that might look a bit strange): `dict.setdefault(k[, d])`:

```
for key, val in favorites.iteritems():
    likes.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

Thank you for the +20 in rep -- I went from 1989 to 2009 in 30 seconds. Let's remember it is 20 years since the Wall fell in Europe..

Comment: Ah, nice. defaultdict seems like the "right" solution here, but that's a cool alternative.

Comment: Note that the first example at http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples explicitly states that using a `defaultdict` is faster than using the `setdefault` method.

Comment: Another caveat is that the value must be mutable, this won't work: `likes.setdefault(key, 0) += 1`

Comment: One more consideration for setdefault: it will evaluate both of its arguments, so even if the key exists, you will be creating and disposing the empty list anyway.

Comment: setdefault was the way to do it before defaultdict. now it feels a bit awkward

Comment: Ned: I thought CPython had a cache of empty lists for reuse like this, which would speed it up. Can't find a reference now though.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list, likes)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'colors': ['blue', 'red', 'purple'], 'foods': ['apples', 'oranges']})
>>> for i, j in favorites.items():
    d[i].append(j)

>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'desserts': ['ice cream'], 'colors': ['blue', 'red', 'purple', 'yellow'], 'foods': ['apples', 'oranges']})
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers are `defaultdict`, but I'm not sure that's the best way to go about it.  Giving out `defaultdict` to code that expects a dict can be bad. (See: [How do I make a defaultdict safe for unexpecting clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031817/how-do-i-make-a-defaultdict-safe-for-unexpecting-clients) ) I'm personally torn on the matter. (I actually found this question looking for an answer to "which is better, `dict.get()` or `defaultdict`") Someone in the other thread said that you don't want a `defaultdict` if you don't want this behavior all the time, and that might be true.  Maybe using defaultdict for the convenience is the wrong way to go about it.  I think there are two needs being conflated here:

"I want a dict whose default values are empty lists." to which `defaultdict(list)` is the correct solution.

and

"I want to append to the list at this key if it exists and create a list if it does not exist." to which `my_dict.get('foo', [])` with `append()` is the answer.

What do you guys think?