# How to convert defaultdict of defaultdicts [of defaultdicts] to dict of dicts [of dicts]?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, collections

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5029958/1547030), I created a `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s. Now, I'd like to turn that deeply nested dict object back into an ordinary python dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

factory = lambda: defaultdict(factory)
defdict = factory()
defdict['one']['two']['three']['four'] = 5

# defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10886f0c8>, {
#             'one': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10886f0c8>, {
#                 'two': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10886f0c8>, {
#                     'three': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10886f0c8>, {
#                         'four': 5})})})})
```

I assume this is not the right solution:

```
import json

regdict = json.loads(json.dumps(defdict))

# {u'one': {u'two': {u'three': {u'four': 5}}}}
```

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20428703/1547030) is inadequate since it does not recurse on the nested dict(s).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why would you **need** to convert these?

Comment: If you don't want a `defaultdict` in the end, have you considered writing a wrapper that generates things by using `setdefault` on ordinary `dict`s? Making your code slightly more complicated at construction time may be a better solution than making it slightly simpler and then adding an extra complication afterward…

Comment: Anyway, the `json` solution obviously won't work at all if you can have anything besides strings, numbers (where you don't care about the type of the numbers), bools, `None`, lists, and dicts… but you _could_ do something workable with YAML or pickle if you really wanted to. I wouldn't recommend it, but it's worth knowing why you don't want it.

Comment: Good question Martin. I am pickling the resulting dictionaries, and I was getting `PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda>...` I probably would have asked something more specific, like how to solve my initial problem, but I was very curious to know the answer to this specific one, thinking there may have been some clever work with reduce() or something in itertools.

Comment: @samstav: "How do I pickle a recursive `defaultdict` (and I don't care whether I get back `defaultdict` or `dict`)" is a good question; why didn't you ask that in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert The only answer I have to that is the basic response from above.... I was curious about this problem, thinking there may have been a clever solution using reduce() or itertools or something. I knew that I could have asked about the pickling... but I kinda got stuck on this. I have been digging into these parts of python lately and wanted to see if I could learn something new. tl;dr Because I'm a bonehead

Comment: @samstav: The point is this is a clumsy and inefficient thing to do (Martijn's answer is as clean as it's going to get), and if you can instead not do it (either by not creating a `defaultdict` in the first place, or by converting on the fly at pickling time instead of converting the whole thing in-memory, or by just getting the `defaultdict` to pickle so the issue never arises), that's a better solution to almost any problem, and definitely to your specific one.

Comment: I see this, but only now that I've seen the answers. That's why I asked the question though... very often I think there's no efficient/correct way to solve a particular problem, so I need to backtrack until the problem in its current form "goes away". However, also quite often, I come across answers I never thought possible, using features of the language or other smarts that I simply didn't know about. I asked thinking there was something like that -- that I just didn't know about yet.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can recurse over the tree, replacing each `defaultdict` instance with a dict produced by a dict comprehension:

```
def default_to_regular(d):
    if isinstance(d, defaultdict):
        d = {k: default_to_regular(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> factory = lambda: defaultdict(factory)
>>> defdict = factory()
>>> defdict['one']['two']['three']['four'] = 5
>>> defdict
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x103098ed8>, {'one': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x103098ed8>, {'two': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x103098ed8>, {'three': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x103098ed8>, {'four': 5})})})})
>>> default_to_regular(defdict)
{'one': {'two': {'three': {'four': 5}}}}
```

Comment: This is a great solution but will not work on very large dictionaries due to the recursion limit.

Comment: @TennesseeLeeuwenburg: Only if by "very large" you mean "takes up half your memory" or "depth approaching 1000", neither of which is that common of a problem. At any rate, you can solve the first by changing this from top-down to bottom-up recursion, and the second by using a loop over an explicit stack instead of recursion, but either one is going to make your code lot more complicated for a problem that you usually aren't going to have…

Comment: @TennesseeLeeuwenburg: how many dictionaries of depth > 1000 do you think you can create before running into memory issues? Note that you won't run into this issue with *wide* nesting, only with *deep* nesting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just to play devil's advocate: `d = {}; d[None] = d` fits in under 1KB, and `inf > 1000`… If that's cheating, a dict that's just a flat tree of depth 1001 (`d[None][None][None]…[None]=None`) should be a few hundred KB at worst.

Comment: @abarnert: sure, but real-world nested structures are not that deep. And if they are they are wide too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, I know, it's just that the way you phrased your question, well, I think I can create a whole lot of them. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm just saying. I've hit recursion limits before, it can happen. There are plenty of software problems where the available data doesn't fit on a single disk, let alone into memory. It's a less-common case, which is why I prefixed by saying your solution was a great solution.

Comment: Replace `iteritems` by `items` for python3

Comment: If you have nested combination of both of them I mean dict to defaultdicts of dicts or of any order this approach won't work. You may need to change if condition to  `if isinstance(d, defaultdict) or isinstance(d, dict)`

Comment: @ShivamKThakkar: then just use `if isinstance(d, dict):`; `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict` and passes that instance test just as much. And `isinstance()` takes a tuple for the second argument, if you need to test for multiple types where those types are not a subclass of another of the types, you'd use `isinstance(instance, (type1, type2, ...))`.

Comment: is there anyway we can use for example d.default_factory = None, which will convert the defaultdict to dict, but for every defaultdict?

Comment: @MurphyAdam: no.

Answer (score 7):

What you're [actually trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is pickle your recursive `defaultdict`. And you don't care whether you get back a `dict` or a `defaultdict` when unpickling.

While there are a number of ways to solve this (e.g., create a `defaultdict` subclass with its own pickling, or explicitly override the default one with `copyreg`), there's one that's dead trivial.

Notice the error you get when you try it:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(defdict)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x10d7f4c80>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

You can't pickle `lambda`-defined functions, because they're anonymous, meaning there's no way they could ever be unpickled.

But there is literally no reason this function needs to be defined by `lambda`. In particular, you don't even *want* it to be anonymous, because you're explicitly giving it a name. So:

```
def factory(): return defaultdict(factory)
```

And you're done.

Here it is in action:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> def factory(): return defaultdict(factory)
>>> defdict = factory()
>>> defdict['one']['two']['three']['four'] = 5
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(defdict)
b'\x80\x03ccollections\ndefaultdict\nq\x00c__main__\nfactory\nq\x01\x85q\x02Rq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00oneq\x04h\x00h\x01\x85q\x05Rq\x06X\x03\x00\x00\x00twoq\x07h\x00h\x01\x85q\x08Rq\tX\x05\x00\x00\x00threeq\nh\x00h\x01\x85q\x0bRq\x0cX\x04\x00\x00\x00fourq\rK\x05ssss.'
```

There are other cases where using `lambda` instead of `def` for no good reason will cause problems—you can't introspect your functions as well at runtime, you get worse tracebacks in the debugger, etc. Use `lambda` when you want an inherently-anonymous function, or a function you can define in the middle of an expression, but don't use it to save three characters of typing.

Comment: Will the pickled `defaultdict` load without issues in another script where `factory` is not defined?

Comment: I just tested (`with open("d.pickle", "wb") as fh: dump(defdict, fh)` in one script and `with open("d.pickle", "rb") as fh: defdict = load(fh)` in another one), and this results in an `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'factory' on <module '__main__'>`. Converting to plain regular dict as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496899/1878788 helps.