# Django: how to process flat queryset to nested dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a table with data looking like this:

```
|Country|State|City |Street|
|-------|-----|-----|------|
|  USA  | AZ  |city1| str1 |
|  USA  | AZ  |city1| str2 |
|  USA  | AZ  |city2| str1 |
|  USA  | AZ  |city2| str3 |
|  USA  | MN  |city3| str4 |
|  MEX  | CH  |city4| str5 |
|  MEX  | CH  |city4| str6 |
```

What is a proper way to convert this into nested dictionary?
I expect the result looking like this:

```
nested_dict = {
    'USA':{
        'AZ':{
            'city1':['str1','str2'],
            'city2':['str1','str3'], 
        },
        'MN':{
            'city3':['str3','str4'], 
        },
    },
    'MEX':{
        'CH':{
            'city4':['str5','str6'],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: By using tools like `itertools.groupby`. SQL databases are not that good with "hierarchical data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

nested_dict = dd(lambda: dd(lambda: dd(list)))
for m in model.objects.all():
    nested_dict[m.Country][m.State][m.City].append(m.Street)
```

Comment: Should this be `list` instead of `lambda: list`? Now you will obtain references to the `list` class.

Comment: @schwobaseggl How can I then iterate through this `nested_dict` in templates?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Figured it out. I followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496899/6916032)

Comment: @ArtyomIlyin Do you mean in some frontend framework where you have your json dump or in a django template?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I mean in django templates. I tried to pass that `nested_dict` within the context to render the template in `django.views`.