# How to create a nested dictionary in a for loop (not using defaultdict)?

Tags: python, nested

my input looks like this:

```
test_file = [['ref1', 'test1', 2],
             ['ref2', 'test1', 3],
             ['ref3', 'test2', 4],
             ['ref1', 'test2', 4],
             ['ref2', 'test2', 1],
             ['ref1', 'test1', 4],
             ['ref1', 'test1', 5]]
```

And I'm trying to get a nested dictionary like this:

```
desired_output = {'ref1':{'test1':[2,5,4]}, 
                  'ref1':{'test2':[4]}, 
                  'ref2':{'test1':[3]}, 
                  'ref2':{'test2':[1]}, 
                  'ref3':{'test2':[4]}}
```

I tried to use defaultdict by appending the values to the second key, however, I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute
> 'append'

So, I tried this:

```
for entry in test_file:
    nest1 = {}
    try:
        nest1[entry[1]].append(entry[2])
    except KeyError:
        nest1[entry[1]] = [entry[2]]
    try:
        mynestdict[entry[0]].append(nest1)
    except KeyError:
        mynestdict[entry[0]] = [nest1]

print(dict(mynestdict))
```

But I'm getting this:

```
{'ref1': [{'test1': [2]}, {'test2': [4]}, {'test1': [4]}, {'test1': [5]}], 
'ref2': [{'test1': [3]}, {'test2': [1]}], 
'ref3': [{'test2': [4]}]}
```

I'm not familiar with nested dictionaries and I really would like to understand them, any suggestions?

Comment: Show your code with `defaultdict()` so we can help you fix it.

Comment: your desired output is not valid, you can't have duplicate `ref1` keys.

Comment: ditto dictionary has a duplicate key alternate can be  '{"ref1":{"test1":[2,4,5],"test2":[4]},"ref2":{"test1":[3],"test2":[1]},"ref3":{"test2":[4]}}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the output you're looking for is this, combining the duplicate keys:

```
{'ref1': {'test1': [2, 4, 5], 'test2': [4]}, 'ref2': {'test1': [3], 'test2': [1]}, 'ref3': {'test2': [4]}}
```

To get that, just check if the nested keys exist, and if they don't, then create them. You asked for code that doesn't use `collections.defaultdict` and it doesn't make it too much more:

```
test_file = [['ref1', 'test1', 2],
             ['ref2', 'test1', 3],
             ['ref3', 'test2', 4],
             ['ref1', 'test2', 4],
             ['ref2', 'test2', 1],
             ['ref1', 'test1', 4],
             ['ref1', 'test1', 5]]

d = {}
for el in test_file:
    if el[0] not in d:
        d[el[0]] = {}
    if el[1] not in d[el[0]]:
        d[el[0]][el[1]] = []

    d[el[0]][el[1]].append(el[2])

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating nested dictionaries, you need nested `defaultdict()`.

```
result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for key1, key2, value in test_file:
    result[key1][key2].append(value)

pprint(default_to_regular(result))
# Output:
{'ref1': {'test1': [2, 4, 5], 'test2': [4]},
 'ref2': {'test1': [3], 'test2': [1]},
 'ref3': {'test2': [4]}}
```

Get `default_to_regular()` from [How to convert defaultdict of defaultdicts [of defaultdicts] to dict of dicts [of dicts]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496831/how-to-convert-defaultdict-of-defaultdicts-of-defaultdicts-to-dict-of-dicts-o)

Answer (score 1):

```
test_file = [['ref1', 'test1', 2],
             ['ref2', 'test1', 3],
             ['ref3', 'test2', 4],
             ['ref1', 'test2', 4],
             ['ref2', 'test2', 1],
             ['ref1', 'test1', 4],
             ['ref1', 'test1', 5]]


df = pd.DataFrame(test_file)


df.groupby([0, 1])[2].apply(np.array).unstack().agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1).to_json()


'{"ref1":{"test1":[2,4,5],"test2":[4]},"ref2":{"test1":[3],"test2":[1]},"ref3":{"test2":[4]}}'
```