# Lock in keys of a defaultdict?

Tags: python

I want to use a defaultdict to initialize a dictionary.

```
d = collections.defaultdict(set)

for i in range(3):
  d[i].add(True)
```

This would result in a dictionary with keys `1..3` and values of `{True}` for each.
Later I want to iterate through the values of this set like so:

```
for b in d[10]:
  print(b)
```

In a standard dictionary, this would throw because `10` is not a key of the dict. In a default dict, this would initialize `10` with an empty set and not throw.

Is there a way to "lock in" the keys of a defaultdict without copying all of the keys to a new dict? Is `d = dict(d)` an `O(1)` op?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert defaultdict to dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428636/how-to-convert-defaultdict-to-dict)

Comment: `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, not a wrapper around an ordinary `dict`. If the later were true, you could simply extract a reference to the wrapped `dict` and discard the `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an O(1) operation, as a *new* dict is created by *copying* the existing keys and values from the default dict. A demonstration:

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> for i in range(3):
...    d[i].add(True)
...
>>> d2 = dict(d)
>>> d[10].add(9)  # Modify the default dict
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {0: {True}, 1: {True}, 2: {True}, 10: {9}})
>>> d2
{0: {True}, 1: {True}, 2: {True}}
```

As you can see, `d` is modified, but not the `dict` created from `d` before the modification was made.