# How can I compare dates in a single json file by comparing the elements in the list with each other?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having a problem, basically I have a json file containing data with identical keys, it's a dictionary exactly, my aim is to check and compare the date/time difference between them, Help me I'm going crazy, I'm missing something , I publish the json file and the Python code, thank you very much, you are fantastic.

P.S:
Sorry for my English, I use Google Translate.

**file data.json:**

```
[{
    "Day": "Giornata 29",
    "Matches": {
        "Home": "Egnatia",
        "Away": "Kukesi",
        "Times": "19.03. 15:00",
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
    }
},{
    "Day": "Giornata 29",
    "Matches": {
        "Home": "Egnatia",
        "Away": "Kukesi",
        "Times": "20.03. 16:09",
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024"
    }
},{
    "Day": "Giornata 41",
    "Matches": {
        "Home": "Lincoln",
        "Away": "Leyton Orient",
        "Times": "19.03. 16:00",
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nINGHILTERRA League One\n2023/2024"
    }
},
{
    "Day": "Giornata 30",
    "Matches": {
        "Home": "Napoli",
        "Away": "Atalanta",
        "Times": "30.03. 12:30",
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nITALIA Serie A\n2023/2024"
    }
}]
```

**Code Python:**

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import time
import json

with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    fileData = json.load(f)
    f.close()



day = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m. %H:%M')

championship = set([d['Matches']['Championship'] for d in fileData])
day= set([q['Day'] for q in fileData])
time = set([s['Matches']['Times'] for s in fileData])

championshipList = [[d for d in fileData if d['Matches']['Championship'] == a] for a in championship]

dayList = [[e for e in fileData if e['Day'] == h] for h in day]

timeList = [[w for w in fileData if w['Matches']['Times'] == c] for c in time]
```

Basically, I have to check the "Day" key first, then the "Championship" key, then I still have to check the "Times" key and compare it with each other, I want to get the time difference from each other, like day or minute or hour, do you have any advice?

**UnicornOnAzur's answer is correct, however I would like to better understand the concept of the code, I have known Python for a few weeks and the concept written below is not clear to me**

Comment: In summary, I would like to calculate how much time difference they have between them.

Comment: For the example input that you show, exactly what should the result be? Also: are you really asking about what to do with the `timeList` values that you get from your code, to get from there to the answer? If that is the question, then *it should not matter* how we got this far.

Comment: @x__SHARINGAN____x, if you can tell what elements are unclear, I'll happily try and explain them to you.

Comment: @UnicornOnAzur
 First of all, I thank you from the bottom of my heart for your kindness, basically I don't exactly understand the part where you insert the ".append(file)" function, what do you mean by "file"? you don't have a variable open to insert data. Continue...

Comment: @UnicornOnAzur
 I also don't understand the "championships" variable what logic it has, and I don't even understand the final part -> "list(map(lambda t: t[-1]-t[0], zip(times, times[1:]) ))" exactly where it says t[-1]-t[0] and immediately after the times[1:] function, I don't understand this index logic, could you please explain these pieces of code to me in more detail? Do you have third party links with specific documentation? I think I should learn these new features... Thank you so much for everything ❤️

Comment: @x__SHARINGAN____x, I've added more explanation and third party reference to the answer. The index logic is taken the last element, `t[-1]`, and the first element, `t[0]`, of the tuple. Using the index `[-1]` always gives you the last element. It would also work with `t[1]`.

Comment: yes, I understand, but by trying to modify your code I can't discard all the days that have at least one game with a time difference less than x minutes

Comment: plus I can't print "Home" and "Away" either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to first check `Day` then `Championship` and then `Times` this code does that for you and then prints the time difference. I've added comments to explain what it does.

```
import collections
import typing
import datetime
import json

with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    fileData: dict = json.load(f)
    # no f.close() is needed as the context manager handles this

# create a default dictionary with nested default dictionary that has a list in it
# the resulting structure is {key:{sub_key:[]}}
similar: collections.defaultdict = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(list))

for soccer_match in fileData:
    # for every file put it into the dictionary based on the day and the championship
    # here you can append the variable because the type of the value of the inner dict is a list
    similar[soccer_match["Day"]][soccer_match["Matches"]["Championship"]].append(soccer_match)

# make a dictionary from the defaultdict
# the structure now is {day: {championship 
championships: dict[dict[list]] = {k:dict(v) for k,v in similar.items()}

# loop over the days
for day in championships:
    # loop over the championships
    for championship in championships.get(day):
        # get the values
        values: list = championships.get(day).get(championship)
        # extract the times and parse the string to a timestamp and sort the list
        times: list = sorted([datetime.datetime.strptime(val.get("Matches").get("Times"), "%d.%m. %H:%M") for val in values])
        # calculate the time difference for every element and its adjacent element
        # if the list has one or no elements return None
        time_difference: typing.Union[None|list] = None if len(times) <= 1 else list(map(lambda t: t[-1]-t[0], zip(times, times[1:])))
        print(day, championship, time_difference)
```

You can format the output of the time difference.

**EDIT**
I've put in type hinting to show what the type is of the variables I assign. Here is a list of articles explaining elements in the solution:

- [Type hinting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QORvB-_mbZ0)
- [Context managers](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/)
- [Default dicts](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python)
- [Default dict to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428636/how-to-convert-defaultdict-to-dict)
- [Map function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/)
- [Lambda function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/)

Comment: As soon as I get home I'll try it, you understand exactly what I'd like to achieve, yesterday I was going crazy, I tried everything but without getting the desired results, I'll update you on it and thanks for the reply.

Comment: why at the end of the code do you call the zip() containing times and times[1:]? what changes between them? ok that the times[1:] takes all the elements from the second record onwards, but the simple times? what changes?

Comment: To calculate the time difference between one time and the next in the list I first create tuples where every tuple is such a pair. So `times` is the original list, `times[1:]` is the same list shifted one place further. Then the `zip` creates an iterable of tuples from these to lists. You can see what it does by calling `print(list(zip(times, times[1:])))` within the loop. This is something I do sometimes to understand what my code is doing.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the clarifications!!! you were very kind!

Comment: , What if I would also like to print "Home" and "Away"?

Comment: You can add that to the print statement.